# load .swf file from sd card and play

Tags: android, flash, webview

I am new in android development.I am developing an app,that can load a file path of .swf file from sd card, then want to play in webView. I don't want to use html file from android_asset folder. here is my code.this code show blank page.In this case what should i do?

`public class FlashFile extends Activity{

```
String sdCardFilePath;
private WebView mWebView;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flash_view);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);


    Bundle gotBusket = getIntent().getExtras();
    sdCardFilePath = gotBusket.getString("key");

    mWebView = new WebView(this);
     mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
     mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

     mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
     mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

     mWebView.loadUrl("file://"+sdCardFilePath);





}`
```